# Buttons in ListBox

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm doing a list in my project, that needs a button for each item.

How can I get those buttons in ListBox, like in the page "Last calls" of my windows phone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to get round buttons is to user [Coding4Fun](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com). It is free to use and very simple to install.

You can follow [these instructions](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/getting-started-with-coding4fun-button-controls) to use it in your application.

As for the icons, you can either search around for some free packs or you can see if [Metro Studio 2](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) has the icon you need. That tool is also free to use.

Answer (score 2):

FunksMaName answer is very much correct except a Small change.....

```
<ListBox Height="360"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="22,23,0,0"
          Name="UserDetailsListBox"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="413">  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                          <Image Source="/Assets/Images/MyImage.png" />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
               <TextBlock x:Name="txtOverViewHeader1"
                          Text="OverView"
                          Foreground="Yellow"
                          Width="600"
                          FontSize="28"
                          Margin="10,0,0,0"
                          Height="65">
                </TextBlock>
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate></ListBox.ItemTemplate></ListBox>
```

i just moved image inside button's template instead of content  ... That is more accurate..

Answer (score 1):

We may  add button for each item of the Listbox like this.

```
<ListBox Height="360"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  Margin="22,23,0,0"
                  Name="UserDetailsListBox"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Width="413">
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                               >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn1" Content="Button1"                                 Margin="0,-20,0,0"/>
                       <TextBlock x:Name="txtOverViewHeader1"
                                  Text="OverView"
                                  Foreground="Yellow"
                                  Width="600"
                                  FontSize="28"
                                  Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                  Height="65">
                        </TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>

             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Width="150" Height="50" x:Name="Btn2" Content="Button2"                                 Margin="0,-20,0,0"/>
                       <TextBlock x:Name="txtOverViewHeader2"
                                  Text="OverView"
                                  Foreground="Yellow"
                                  Width="600"
                                  FontSize="28"
                                  Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                  Height="65">
                        </TextBlock>
                     </StackPanel>

                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                </ListBox>
```

Hope it will give you the desired answer

Comment: I was trying something like this, but I need those "circles" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use a circular image, and set the Tap event, or wrap your image around a Button template if you need a buttons specific behavior

```
<ListBox Height="360"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="22,23,0,0"
              Name="UserDetailsListBox"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="413"> 
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Template="x:Null" Tap="">
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Images/MyImage.png" />
                    </Button>
                   <TextBlock x:Name="txtOverViewHeader1"
                              Text="OverView"
                              Foreground="Yellow"
                              Width="600"
                              FontSize="28"
                              Margin="10,0,0,0"
                              Height="65">
                    </TextBlock>
                 </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: I found this page: http://nirmitk26.blogspot.com.br/2011/02/round-button-in-windows-phone-7.html  but it looks too complicated.